# Picasso loading images results in 403 forbidden,

Tags: android, iis, file-permissions, http-status-code-403, picasso

I have a system (c#, IIS) that allows users to create folders and put some images in it, the system itself works just fine, the folders are created and images are accessible through system itself and also as an standalone links browsed by any browser, but on the other hand I have to load those images on android device and I'm using picasso... based on below code and the exception It throws 403 forbidden ... I copy pasted the image link in my browser and it was fine but on android device it did not work.

```
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(_ctx).listener(new Picasso.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso arg0, Uri arg1, Exception arg2) {
                Log.e("Error while loading images", arg2.getMessage());
            }
        }).build();
        picasso.load(item_first.getImage().replace("~", _URL_IMAGE).replace(" ", "%20")).into(btn_first, new Callback()
        {

            @Override
            public void onError() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                _dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

the folder structure is like root -> Images -> Upload -> [new folders go here] -> files 
the upload folder has full control (I know it's not a good idea at all but just to test I gave it full control) to the IIS application pool but still not working.

**EDIT:** here's the log file from the server for image loading requests:

```
Fields: date time s-sitename s-computername s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs-version cs(User-Agent) cs(Cookie) cs(Referer) cs-host sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status sc-bytes cs-bytes time-taken

2014-08-13 05:54:51 W3SVC29 WIN-BEII7BVNSAM 79.143.84.91 GET /mobile/getCategories - 80 - 91.99.5.187 HTTP/1.1 - - - behdis-panel.ir 200 0 0 374 85 75


2014-08-13 05:54:51 W3SVC29 WIN-BEII7BVNSAM 79.143.84.91 GET /mobile/getSubsForCategory id=9 80 - 91.99.5.187 HTTP/1.1 - - - behdis-panel.ir 200 0 0 407 95 73


2014-08-13 05:55:08 W3SVC29 WIN-BEII7BVNSAM 79.143.84.91 GET /mobile/getProductsForCriteria sub_id=8&batch=0 80 - 91.99.5.187 HTTP/1.1 - - - behdis-panel.ir 200 0 0 400 111 139


**2014-08-13 05:55:08 W3SVC29 WIN-BEII7BVNSAM 79.143.84.91 GET /Images/Upload/ ????%20????/Women%20Free%20Run%205/f6bb102959c84fd3b5492173168a056b.jpg 80 - 91.99.5.187 HTTP/1.1 Dalvik/1.6.0+(Linux;+U;+Android+4.1.2;+LG-E975+Build/JZO54K) - - behdis-panel.ir 403 14 0 1318 248 99


2014-08-13 05:55:57 W3SVC29 WIN-BEII7BVNSAM 79.143.84.91 GET /mobile/getProductsForCriteria sub_id=8&batch=0 80 - 91.99.5.187 HTTP/1.1 - - - behdis-panel.ir 200 0 0 400 111 45



**2014-08-13 05:55:57 W3SVC29 WIN-BEII7BVNSAM 79.143.84.91 GET /Images/Upload/ ????%20????/Women%20Free%20Run%205/f6bb102959c84fd3b5492173168a056b.jpg 80 - 91.99.5.187 HTTP/1.1 Dalvik/1.6.0+(Linux;+U;+Android+4.1.2;+LG-E975+Build/JZO54K) - - behdis-panel.ir 403 14 0 1318 248 45
```

the ones with the ** at the beginning are the requests to load the image , as you can see both returned http 403

**EDIT:** Ok I've found something strange, this only happens for those folders that has persian names such as "تست" which is "test" in persian, it cannot access the folder in the device while it works fine on browser, any idea?

Comment: When you examined your server logs, to see what the HTTP request was, what did you learn?

Comment: sadly I don't have access to server at the moment, all I've been given is a parallels plesk control panel to change the permissions, what confuses me is that I can access the images via browser but not picasso... doesn't picasso use simple http to download images?

Comment: "isn't picasso uses simple http to download images?" -- yes, which is why having access to your server logs would help you determine where things are going wrong. For example, Picasso may URL-encode your URL for you, in which case the `replace(" ", "%20")` would be unnecessary (and potentially the source of your issue).

Comment: "Picasso may URL-encode your URL for you", I've been using picasso for quiet some time and everytime I did not replace white spaces myself it gave 400 Bad Request and doing that fixed it. anyway I removed the replacing part of the code and now it gave 400 Bad Request so I assume I have to put it back there, by the way I'm using the same system for another domain and it's working completely fine, even with the replacing in the place.

Comment: @CommonsWare Edited my original post with the server logs